# проблемы с seo url в opencart

Tags: opencart

В движке опенкарт в настройках мы подключили seo_url, но с адресами у нас возникла проблема.
Например, у нас есть такой адрес: http://site.ru/remont  и site.ru/kontakty – когда в УРЛ адрес в ручную вводим http://site.ru/remont/kontakty открывается страница контакты но должно было выдать ошибку 404.
Такая проблема со всеми УРЛ адресами, не зависимо что это за страница: если вводим УРЛ адрес какого-то каталога потом любой другой адрес, то УРЛ открывается так, как написали, но содержание всегда выдается то, которое указано в конечном адресе в УРЛ-е.
Вот еще несколько примеров:

site.ru/remont/kontakty  --открывается страница контакты

site.ru/proektirovanie/dostavka-i-oplata   --открывается страница  доставка и оплата

site.ru/dizain/o-nas   --открывается страница о нас

site.ru/fasadnye-raboty/novosti  --открывается Новости

Answer (score 0):

Там видимо в файле common/seo_url.php есть строчка

```
foreach ($parts as $part) {
```

Попробуйте её заменить на строчку:

```
if ($part = implode("-", $parts)){
```